# Join the element in the array and remove some element from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I got a little problem to save array into csv. The array of x that I have is like below,

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, ',' , 4, 5, 6, 7, ',' , 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]
```

I want to save x as

```
x = [123, 4567, 89123]
```

Comment: `x.join('').split(',').map(Number)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3, ',', 4, 5, 6, 7, ',', 8, 9, 1, 2, 3];
console.log(x.join('').split(',').map(Number));
```

Please avoid using var keyword [difference between let & const](https://dev.to/sarah_chima/var-let-and-const--whats-the-difference-69e)

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, ',' , 4, 5, 6, 7, ',' , 8, 9, 1, 2, 3];

console.log(array.join('').split(',').map(Number));
```

Comment: This will be returning an array of strings, using .map(Number) will return an array of numbers

Comment: you are right @PremKumar. In a hurry, I havent gone through the answer. thanks for finding the bug